# Viability of LVM snapshots for creating multiple versions of a filesystem on a backup storage device

Tags: rhel, lvm, backup, snapshot

I have a largish main storage disk of 400TiB that we plan to backup to a remote JBOD. The backup tools provided with the main storage only allow for dumping a single copy of the filesystem, and then updating it via scheduled incrementals.

We would like some additional DR protection by creating multiple snapshots of the backed-up filesystem on the JBOD (space allowing). How viable is it to use LVM snapshots for this use case? I know they are more designed to freeze the filesystem to take a backup.

My thinking would be prior to any incremental backup, we first snapshot the backup filesystem. Then the incremental runs as normal to update the original backup.

This way if there was some corruption on the main storage that was copied to the backup, we can still restore the backup to an earlier point in time. We would keep some number of snapshots depending on disk space on the JBOD / data 'churn'.

Does this sound at all feasable? Is there another tool I should be considering?

We are a RHEL shop so would prefer to stay in that known territory.

Comment: In the event that you need to restore the backup due to corruption, will the backup tools be able to produce a correct incremental given that it's perception of the previous state may no longer match the backup you've restored? In other words, how well can the backup tools perform a retry?